# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found - Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, swift4, provisioning-profile

I know there have been a lot of posts about this, but I still can't find a solution for myself.

Here is the error I get:[image]

I hear somewhere, that it might be something related to a your free apple id account developer expiring in a week's time and I checked mine and this is what I got:

[image]

Does this have something to do with it and if not, then can someone please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Un check automatic manage , change bundle id , check it agin , select the developer account

Comment: After that I get an error, could not write to device

Comment: you use free or paid account ?? remove all versions of the app from device , clean remove derived data

Comment: Free account. Uninstalled app from device and removed derived data, but still no luck

Comment: in general add any 3 random characters to the bundle id and click enter

Comment: do you see a progress under developer name loading when you did that which creating the provision profiles ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165184/discussion-between-arnav-gupta-and-sh-khan).